# Sqlite - One-To-Many Relationship SELECT Query

Tags: python, database, sqlite, group-by, one-to-many

### Prequisites

There are two tables in my file (it's about vinyl records):

Records

| ID | Title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Title_1 |
| 2 | Title_2 |

Styles

| ID | recordId | style |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Blues |
| 2 | 1 | Disco |
| 3 | 2 | Blues |
| 4 | 2 | Electro |

(Styles.style is stored as an Integer but a String is used for simplicity here)

Following condition is set for table Styles:
Styles.recordId = Records.ID for every given vinyl record

->This is necessary to find all styles related to one specific vinyl record

Therefore, there are two vinyls stored:

Title_1 has two styles Blues, Disco 
Title_2 has two styles Blues, Electro

### Question

In my SELECT query, I want to find vinyl records with a certain style

#### Find Titles with one style

If I want to find a vinyl record with one specific style, it seems pretty straight forward. 
I use:

```
SELECT Records.Title
FROM Records
JOIN Styles ON Styles.recordId = Records.ID
WHERE Styles.style=Disco
```

With the desired result:

```
(Title_1)
```

#### Find Titles with more styles

Let`s say, I want to find all titles with the styles (Blues AND Electro)
Using the statement from before and just adding another statement does not seem to work:

```
SELECT Records.Title
FROM Records
JOIN Styles ON Styles.recordId = Records.ID
WHERE Styles.style=Blues AND Styles.style=Electro
```

This does not work as the column Styles.style never consists of both styles at the same time.

How can I tell SQLite to return all titles that satisfy the requirement? The output should be

```
(Title_2)
```

EDIT: Fixed tables not rendering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you need to filter the rows of your resultset for the styles that you want and aggregation with the condition in the `HAVING` clause that for a title both styles exist:

```
SELECT r.id, r.Title
FROM Records r JOIN Styles s 
ON s.recordId = r.ID
WHERE s.style IN ('Blues', 'Electro')
GROUP BY r.id, r.Title
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

I assume that in the table `style` the combination of the columns `recordId` and `style` is unique.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was so close, but totally missed the "HAVING" statement. Problem solved!